# Reuse mongodb connection in ruby script

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a ruby script with several connections to a MongoDB I've since found that each query/insert is opening a new connection leaving me lots of connections in use.

ruby-2.0.0p195-2.el6.x86_64 & mongodb-2.4.12-1.el6.x86_64

I have several connections as per the examples below throughout my script. How do I use a single, or as few as possible connections so that I don't end up with 100's in use at any one time. My script is split into `def foo` / `end` chunks where some blocks have just 1 db action, others have 3 or 4.

```
#Insert into db
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("room1-web")
coll = db.collection("room1")
coll.update({"_id" =>a}, rabbitdb, {upsert:true})

#Insert into db
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("room1-web")
coll = db.collection("room1")
coll.update({"_id" =>b}, chickendb, {upsert:true})

#Do query on db to update indicators etc.
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("room1-indi-lookup")
coll = db.collection("elements")
kitty = coll.find({"_id" => table[address][i], "state" => char}, :fields => {"_id" => 0, "state" => 0}).to_a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@conn = Mongo::Connection.new("localhost", 27017, :pool_size => 5, :pool_timeout => 5)
db = @conn.db(.....)
```

Comment: Ahh cool. So I just define the global var `@con` then modify my code to use `@con.db` instead of creating a new connection each time. I'll give it try later on and see how it goes. Thanks